# Using anonymous function taking a few parameters

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function

***Script example.***

```
function TakeCallback(param, param2, callback) {
     var a = param;
     var b = param2;
     callback(a, b);
}

.... some context ...
TakeCallback("A", "B", function(one, two) {
    var scopeA = one;
    var scopeB = two;
});
```

***in C#***

```
public void FuncWithCallback(int param, int param2, Func callback) 
{
    int myScope = param;
    int myScope2 = param2;

    callback(myScope, myScope2);
}

.... some context ....

.
.
    FuncWithCallBack(10, 100, (x, y) => {
        int AnotherScope = x;
        int AnotherScope2 = y;
    });
.
.
```

**Question**

My question is pretty simple. How can I use a callback function in C# like what script does? More accurately, what's the correct syntax to do that in the third parameter of

```
public void FuncWithCallback(int param, int param2, Func callback)
```

Is it going to look like this?

```
public void FuncWithCallback(int param, int param2, Func(x, y) callback)
// beep! error!
```

If there's several options for this, please tell me as many as possible. I'm ready to learn :D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use generics and built-in delegates:

```
public void FuncWithCallback(int param, int param2, Action<int, int> callback)
```

[Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) is a delegate that can take parameters and return something. [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) returns void and can take parameters. You can also declare your own [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) types if you want to have more explicit naming.

```
// Action
delegate void MyDelegate();

// Action<int, int>
delegate void MyDelegate2(int param1, int param2);

// Func<string>
delegate string MyDelegate3();

// Func<int, int, string>
delegate string MyDelegate4(int param1, int param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is are the way in which you can used call back function in C#

Option  1

```
public static void FunctionWithCallBack(string a, string b, Func<string,string,string> callBackFunc)
    {
        string firstArg = a;
        string secondArg = b;
        var result = callBackFunc(firstArg, secondArg);
    }

    public static string CallBackFunctionMethod(string a, string b)
    {
        return a + " " +  b;
    }
CallBackFunction.FunctionWithCallBack("Aslam", "Shaikh", CallBackFunction.CallBackFunctionMethod);
```

Option 2

```
CallBackFunction.FunctionWithCallBack("Aslam", "Shaikh", (x, y) => x + " " + y );
```

Let me know if you have any questions